# ASUS Memo Pad 10 Android upgrade

Tags: updates, tablet

Does anyone achieve to upgrade his ASUS Memo Pad 10 to Android 4.4 or later (5.0) ?

It seems like there's no solutions for this, I've search on xda developpers and on cyanogen, without finding anything. There are performance issues which annoy me and I would like to resolve them by getting a newer android version.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: It looks like the only asus devices to be enought popular and lucky to have a cyanogenmod port are mostly the Transformes series.

Comment: Yep, saw that... But maybe someone found a trick for the Memo Pad !

Comment: There are no tricks in porting a ROM, it's all about hard work.